# Add a document from SharePoint to Dynamics CRM Workflow's Email

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm-online

I have a requirement where I need to add a document from SharePoint to Dynamics CRM Workflow in which I have a step to send Email.

Is this achievable? Also, is there any workaround where I can get this done?
Kindly advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible out of the box, but what you could do is, create a custom workflow activity and programmatically read the file from SharePoint and write the byte array to the activity body as a base64 string, create an email and attach the file to the email as an attachment and send it away.

```
        var email = new Email
        {
            Subject = "Email with attachment from SharePoint.",
            Description = "Find the document attached.",
            From =
                new[]
                {
                    new ActivityParty() { PartyId = new CrmEntityReference(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName, fromUserGuid) }
                },
            To =
                new[]
                {
                    new ActivityParty() { PartyId = new CrmEntityReference(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName, toUserGuid) }
                },
            DirectionCode = true
        };

        var emailId = organizationService.Create(email);

        var sampleAttachment = new ActivityMimeAttachment()
        {
            ObjectId = new CrmEntityReference(Email.EntityLogicalName, emailId),
            ObjectTypeCode = Email.EntityLogicalName,
            Subject = "File attached from sharepoint",
            Body = Convert.ToBase64String(new byte[] { }), //replace the bytes with the file bytes read from SharePoint
            FileName = "sharepointattachment.txt"
        };

        organizationService.Create(sampleAttachment);

        var sendEmailMessageRequest = new SendEmailRequest() { EmailId = emailId, IssueSend = true };
        var sendEmailResponse = (SendEmailResponse)organizationService.Execute(sendEmailMessageRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll let you know if this works for me.. :)